# Text box selection drag direction

Tags: windows, ubuntu, google-chrome, firefox

Often I am in a program or web page and need to drag-select text in a one-line text box - say to remove part of a search query and replace it with another. What often happens is I'll select, type the replacement text and hit return so quickly as to miss the problem: the selected text moved to the opposite side of the cursor and I replace the wrong text.

Not all text boxes do this, for instance the search bar in Chromium for Ubuntu never has the issue but the title text-box in this question will do it. If one were to click text in this title text box say half way along and drag to the right it should in theory always select the text following the point where the drag started. In this text box though, if the rightward drag includes a small upward movement, the selected text is on the wrong side. Similarly if dragging to the left, to select the text left of the cursor, any downward movement will select what is to the right of the cursor. It seems that drag selection in these boxes has an approximately 50/50 chance of selecting the correct text, based on where the cursor ends, with left+up and right+down being the two 'correct' actions.

So the simple questions: Is there any global system setting in Ubuntu/Windows that changes this behaviour? Similarly is there and browser setting in Chrome/Firefox browser or that changes this behaviour? Is the problem instead with the software or web developer where they should be doing something different to prevent this? Is the only answer that the 
user (me) is just more careful and attentive?

**Edit:**
I found a video of this behaviour suggesting Chrome is the culprit or at least has the same kind of issue. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LH4_fhbNTBw).

Comment: I don't see this sort of a problem with the question title text box.

Comment: Bizarre, what browser do you use?

Comment: Firefox on Windows.